# Pandas: joining two tables on datetime datetime64[ns] fails

Tags: python, pandas, join, python-3.7

Does anyone know why joining on `datetime64[ns]` does not work while it does work if those same columns are set as index? This is really strange and feels like a bug or is there any explanation?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1,2,3],
    "t": pd.to_datetime([1556979766, 1556979767, 1556979768], unit="s")
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "b": [5,3,3],
    "t": pd.to_datetime([1556979766, 1556979767, 1556979768], unit="s")
})
df1.join(df2, on="t")

>> ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

While this works:

```
df1.index = df1.t
df2.index = df2.t
df1.join(df2, lsuffix="1")
```

`dtypes` are identical

```
list(df1.dtypes) == list(df2.dtypes)
>> True
```

(pandas version: `'0.24.2'`)

Comment: have you tried `df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='t')`?

Comment: @aws_apprentice the same, I think the method doesn't matter since it will first evaluate the statements leading to the error!

Comment: @meow: I think it's just the way `join` works: `on` parameter only refers to the **caller** DataFrame. Here's from the documentation about `on`: Column or index level name(s) in the **caller** to join on the **index in other**, otherwise joins index-on-index. So it tries to join by `df1`'s `t` column and `df2`'s index, which results in type mismatch

Comment: `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='t')` should work here

Comment: @perl thanks that makes sense, I assumend it would join it on the specified column for both dataframes.

Comment: @meow what I suggested worked for me

Comment: @aws_apprentice you are right, with merge it does work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @perl suggested, `df1.join(df2, on='t')` will try to match `df1.t` to `df2.index`, in this case `int64`. Another way around this is

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('t'), on='t')
```

Or use `merge`. where you can specify which columns to use on both sides.

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='t', right_on='t')
```